# What is wrong with this use of "forEach"?

Tags: javascript

I expect the `errorLogArrayList.length` to be 3, but the result is 2.

Could anyone please tell me why this code doesn't work as I expect and how to fix it?

**CODE:**

```
var logArrayList = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,"error"],
    [1,2,"error"],
    [1,2,"error"]
]

var errorLogArrayList = [];

console.log(logArrayList);
console.log("======================");


logArrayList.forEach(function(logArray, index, self) {

    if(logArray[2] === "error") {

        var errorArray = self.splice(index, 1)[0];
        errorLogArrayList.push(errorArray);

    }

}); 

// I expect this value to be 3, but the result is 2.
console.log("errorLogArrayList.length is " +  errorLogArrayList.length)

console.log(errorLogArrayList);

console.log("======================");

// I expect this value to be 1, but the result is 2.
console.log("logArrayList.length is " + logArrayList.length);
console.log(logArrayList);
```

**LOG:**

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 2, 'error' ],
  [ 1, 2, 'error' ],
  [ 1, 2, 'error' ] ]
======================
// I expect this value to be 3, but the result is 2.
errorLogArrayList.length is 2
[ [ 1, 2, 'error' ], [ 1, 2, 'error' ] ]
======================
//I expect this value to be 1, but the result is 2.
logArrayList.length is 2
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 'error' ] ]
```

Comment: Don't modify the array you are iterating over.

Comment: @zerkms so, what I should do is to clone the original array and do the rest?

Comment: @zenkms is it ok to modify an array if I modify only one array, not two array at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) operation:

```
var errorLogArrayList = logArrayList.filter(function(array) {
  return array[2] === 'error';
});

logArrayList = logArrayList.filter(function(array) {
  return array[2] !== 'error';
});
```

Unfortunately this requires some duplicate iterations. You can use [_.partition from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#partition) if you want (looks a little cleaner):

```
var lists = _.partition(logArrayList, function(array) {
  return array[2] === 'error';
});

var errorLogArrayList = lists[0];

logArrayList = lists[1];
```

The problem with your current approach is that you are trying to keep track of multiple states and modify two arrays at the same time, and this is leading to some data conflicts. `filter` is usually a little more declarative, and it doesn't mutate the original array, but instead returns a new one.

## Edit

Wanted to add a method with `reduce` as suggested by @zerkms in the comments:

```
var lists = logArrayList.reduce(function(agg, curr) {
  if(curr[2] === 'error') {
    agg[0] = (agg[0] || []).concat([curr]);
  } else {
    agg[1] = (agg[1] || []).concat([curr]);
  }

  return agg;
}, []);
```

That does the same as the `partition` example.

Comment: ... or `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it now!